# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "A3ADF30029011F"

Tags: java, binary

I'm trying ton convert Hex into decimal and into binary but getting same error for given HEX  `"001F012900F3ADA3"`  but same hex is converted to decimal and into binary using any online convertor.

```
Integer.parseInt("001F012900F3ADA3",16);   // to decimal conversion

Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt("001F012900F3ADA3", 16));   // to binary conversion
```

when i use part of this HEX like `Integer.parseInt("00F3ADA3",16);` this works fine no exception.
is there some type of max hex length allowed to convert or i'm using something wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value that you're trying to parse is too big to fit in integer. To parse this properly you'd have to parse it as long.

If you replace it with below, then it'll work.

```java
Long.toBinaryString(Long.parseLong("001F012900F3ADA3", 16));
```

Answer (score 1):

The max value of int is `2147483647`, value : `001F012900F3ADA3` convert to the Binary number is `8726999899286947`.